# What are these three black cap-like pieces?

Tags: telescope, newtonian-telescope

My son received a secondhand telescope for his birthday. It is a Celestron Powerseeker 114AZ.

I found these three black cap-like pieces separate from other parts. I can’t find what they are or what they do in the instruction manual.

What are they and what do they do?

[image: Here’s a picture of them.]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: If they have glass in them and you can see through them they are some type of lenses.  If the black stuff covers all of one side so you can't see through them they are lens caps.

Comment: @M.A.Golding just black plastic. I initially guessed caps, but with three notches on the sides I didn’t know if they had anything to do with the spider vanes of the secondary mirror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently using a Celestron Astromaster 130 EQ and I also have a similar type of caps.
Starting from left to right, the first two are caps used to cover eyepiece holder in case the lens is not connected with it, and the last one is a cap for the lens. So I think they might have given you one extra cap as a lens holder.